# How to give users FTP perms (vsftpd)

Tags: permissions, users, vsftpd

I can login to my FTP account, unfortunatly I can't do anything... It appears almost as if everything is read only.  I cant make, delete, etc anything.  How do I give myself all the perms on my home server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your `/etc/vsftpd.conf` file.

Change from:

```
#
# Uncomment this to enable any form of FTP write command.
#write_enable=YES
```

Change to:

```
#
# Uncomment this to enable any form of FTP write command.
write_enable=YES
```

Comment: I just checked. It is already like that.  Does it matter if I am editing the file from the root user on the server SSH?

Comment: @joeldesante The permissions matter.  Normal users can't write to system files.

Comment: Never mind, Ignore the above comment... I just tried to edit it with my account, even when I change it I cant seem to do anything in FileZilla.  I cant make, edit, or delete files/dirs.

Comment: How do I allow the user to have the perms.  Srry, I'm new and confused.

Comment: `chmod 777 file` will ensure write access.  You may have to also do that for the directory where you want files to be uploaded to (`chmod 777 [uploaddir]`).    `Upload dir` is the name, without the brackets, of the directory you are giving write access to.

Comment: so if I type `chmod 777 file` I will be able to edit everything on the server via FTP?

Comment: Never mind. I understand it now. Thanks a ton. :D